# Problem executing query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a function which fetches data from database and displays in the JSP in table format.The function is written in java class,which is called in JSP.But the query is not executing.The same query can execute in SQL yog. What could be the problem?

My code goes like this

```
 public ArrayList<CustomReportDTO> getHostAndUserAndResponsereport(String argHostId, String argColoumns, String argStartDate, String argEndDate) {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ArrayList<CustomReportDTO> arrMetrics = new ArrayList<CustomReportDTO>();
        StringBuffer strQuery;
        argStartDate = getDate(argStartDate);
        argEndDate = getDate(argEndDate);
        if (!argColoumns.contains(",")) {
            argColoumns = argColoumns + ",";
        } else {
            argColoumns = argColoumns + ",";
        }

        String[] arrColoumns = argColoumns.split(",");
        try {
            System.out.println("Before Getting Connection");
            con = DBConnect.getInstance().getConnection();
            System.out.println("Connection__________ " + con);
            strQuery = new StringBuffer();
            strQuery.append("SELECT " + argColoumns + " u.Time_stamp AS host_time_stamp,");
            strQuery.append("db1.queryresultset AS Concurrent_Users,");
            strQuery.append("db2.queryresultset AS Active_Users, ");
            strQuery.append("db3.queryresultset AS Logged_Users,");
            strQuery.append("db4.queryresultset AS Anonymous_Users,");
            strQuery.append("urlhs.totalrsptime AS totalrsptime");
            strQuery.append(" FROM ");
            strQuery.append("unix_host_history u, ");
            strQuery.append("db_query_history db1, ");
            strQuery.append("db_query_history db2, ");
            strQuery.append("db_query_history db3, ");
            strQuery.append("db_query_history db4 ,");
            strQuery.append("url_history urlhs ");
            strQuery.append("WHERE ");
            strQuery.append("u.hostid = 'HS001' AND ");
            strQuery.append("db1.compid='CP009' AND ");
            strQuery.append("db2.compid='CP010' AND ");
            strQuery.append("db3.compid='CP011' AND ");
            strQuery.append("db4.compid='CP012' AND ");
            strQuery.append("urlhs.compid='CP013' AND ");

            strQuery.append("SUBSTR(u.time_Stamp,1,15) = SUBSTR(db1.time_stamp,1,15) AND ");
            strQuery.append("SUBSTR(u.time_Stamp,1,15) = SUBSTR(urlhs.time_stamp,1,15) AND ");
            strQuery.append("SUBSTR(db1.time_Stamp,1,15) = SUBSTR(db2.time_stamp,1,15) AND ");
            strQuery.append("SUBSTR(db1.time_Stamp,1,15)= SUBSTR(db3.time_stamp,1,15) AND ");
            strQuery.append("SUBSTR(db1.time_Stamp,1,15) = SUBSTR(db4.time_stamp,1,15) AND ");

            strQuery.append("u.time_stamp > '" + argStartDate + "' AND ");
            strQuery.append("u.time_stamp < '" + argEndDate + "' ");
            strQuery.append("ORDER BY u.time_stamp ");
            System.out.println("Query" + strQuery);
            System.out.println("After Getting Connection_____________");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Stament " +stmt);
            System.out.println("After Creating Statmnet_________________________");
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(strQuery.toString());
            System.out.println("After Excecuting Query______________");

CustomReportDTO objUnix = null;

            if (rs != null) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    objUnix = new CustomReportDTO();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrColoumns.length; i++) {
                        if (arrColoumns[i].equalsIgnoreCase("OpenFilesCount")) {
                            objUnix.setOpenFilesCount(rs.getString("OpenFilesCount"));

 }
                   }
 arrMetrics.add(objUnix);

                }


            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception : ");
            System.out.println(se.getMessage());

        }
        System.out.println("Size Result _______" + arrMetrics.size());
        return arrMetrics;
    }
}
```

I can get the Sysouts till the statement creation.

Answer (score 0):

without an exception to look at, this is just a guess, but maybe the `argColumns` need a comma at the end and don't have one?